# dropdown Arrow unicode icon static position css small devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement an accordion for FAQ. I have problems with the arrow icons in **small screens**, so each time I press the *down arrow* it should be switched for the *up arrow* icon and also located on the same place. But once I click the *down arrow* the *up arrow* appears slightly more on the top (**on smartphone view**). I tried with margin but not success. I would like to know how to keep both icons at the same place each time I switch from one to the other by clicking on it.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
        to highlight the button that controls the panel */
        this.classList.toggle("active");

        /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {

  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
}

button.accordion:after {

  font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS', 'Consolas';
  content: "\2304";

  font-size: 60px !important;
  color: #777;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: -3vh ;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2303";
  max-height: 1vh;


}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="accordion">First Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. </p>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="accordion">Second Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>This is the answer to question #1. Pellentesque habitant morbi....</p>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="accordion">Third Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>This is the answer to question #1. Pellentesque habitant morbi....</p>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="accordion">Fourth Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>This is the answer to question #1. Pellentesque habitant morbi....</p>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="accordion">Fifth Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>This is the answer to question #1. Pellentesque habitant morbi....</p>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="accordion">Sixth Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>This is the answer to question #1. Pellentesque habitant morbi....</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].onclick = function(){
            /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
            to highlight the button that controls the panel */
            this.classList.toggle("active");

            /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
button.accordion {

        background-color: #eee;
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        transition: 0.4s;
        font-size: 18px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .panel p{
      margin: 0;
      padding:10px;
    }

    /* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */

    button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    /* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */

    div.panel {
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: white;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
    }

    button.accordion:after {

        font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS', 'Consolas';
        content: "\2304";

        font-size: 60px !important;
        color: #777;
        position: absolute;
        left: 3%;
        top: -30%;
    }

    button.accordion.active:after {
        content: "\2303";
        max-height: 1vh;


    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="accordion">First Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. </p>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="accordion">Second Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>This is the answer to question #1. Pellentesque habitant morbi....</p>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="accordion">Third Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>This is the answer to question #1. Pellentesque habitant morbi....</p>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="accordion">Fourth Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>This is the answer to question #1. Pellentesque habitant morbi....</p>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="accordion">Fifth Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>This is the answer to question #1. Pellentesque habitant morbi....</p>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="accordion">Sixth Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>This is the answer to question #1. Pellentesque habitant morbi....</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would set the arrow as a background image then change it depending on the state of the button (active or not), then you can position the image as you like. note only use background-position when its in its original state.

```
.accordion{
    background-image: url("down arrow"); //path to image
    background-position: right center; //edit depending on your needs
    }
    .accordion.active{
    background-image: url("up arrow"); //path to image
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**hi try this:** it will work

```
button.accordion{
position:relative;
}

button.accordion::after{
position: absolute;
left: 30px;
top: -16px;
}
```